# Converting HTTP images to HTTPS (and finding backups of the dead link ones)

Tags: discussion

Meta Stack Exchange has announced their [roadmap to serving and uploading HTTPS images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/191265). Any images already uploaded to Stack Exchange's Imgur site will be automatically converted. Those that are linked to external sites will be made link-only.

> After [https] is enabled, old posts that have HTTP images, accessible via HTTPS, will be edited accordingly. This will be an actual markdown change, attributed to the Community user, posts won't be bumped.

We'd like to prevent this from happening. Let's take the time to update our questions to point to HTTPS versions of our questions. Other sites, such as [SciFi/Fantasy Stack Exchange, are undergoing similar efforts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10678/13217). This will unfortunately bump a lot of questions to the front page, but I think that this effort is best in the long run.

This [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/boardgames/query/638496/find-http-images-needing-to-be-converted-to-https) query should find all of them. At the time of this writing, there are 26 questions needing attention, so it's not a huge effort.

It looks to me like the majority of external HTTP images are for Magic cards. Unfortunately, none of the sites, (including Wizards' own [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com)) support HTTPS at this time. Fortunately, we can upload them via the Stack Exchange image uploader, which will automatically future-proof them, as well as make sure they will still exist if the external site goes down.

Speaking of which, it does look like we have a few cases of the external site going down with these images. For instance, I found [Hex board game strategy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/17863/3389) had an externally hosted image to a website that no longer existed. Fortunately, I was able to find it on [Archive.org](https://archive.org) from a few years ago and was able to upload it to Stack Exchange's Imgur.

So to recap:

- Find images that are externally hosted via HTTP
- Either find HTTPS equivalents or upload them via the Stack Exchange image uploader (I think that uploading to SE would be preferable, in case the external link goes down)
- If the external link is dead, try to find an old copy on Archive.org or elsewhere

Comment: FYI, I've been working on this by using the SEDE query, then sorting by number of views and working from top to bottom. Thus the ones more popular are more likely to have already been corrected. There are a few scattered ones I corrected before realizing I could sort.

Comment: For Magic card images, I'd favor just linking to the card, the way most questions do, and quoting the rules text or the relevant part of it if necessary. Generally it's not *that* important that the actual image be there.

Comment: @Jefromi I don't play Magic and so am less familiar with how the Magic questions on this site usually work, but I'd be fine with that. Feel free to edit out the pictures from any of them, including the ones I'd already switched to HTTPS (they should be on the front page).

Comment: Okay, sure. Do you want to also just copy the query results into an answer here so you/we can mark what we've fixed?

Comment: SEDE is off of data dumps, I think weekly, so yeah, it's unfortunately not usable for iteration like this.

Comment: I can work something out, one minute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Done. All external HTTP images have been reuploaded or removed.

Here's everything that SEDE query returns. We can move things into the top section as we take care of them.

Completed:

- [Are there standard board sizes for the industry?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11684/)
- [Is there ANY way to activate a planeswalker ability at instant speed?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23381/) (Could maybe remove the Magic card image altogether)
- [How to defeat an active Digglet Pokemon when oppenent has an additional on bench](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33904/)   (Question)
- [How to defeat an active Digglet Pokemon when oppenent has an additional on bench](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33905/)  (Answer)
- [Reducing the Imperial strategy's power in Twilight Imperium](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/)
- [Are creature effects considered an Instant?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/) (Replaced image of tap icon with userscript syntax)
- [Custom boards for Eclipse](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/19207/)
- [Hex game strategy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/17884/)  (Found image on Archive.org, since site is dead)
- [Can I still crown a king if I run out of pieces?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24664/)
- [What is the special die with pictograms in Monopoly used for?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12680/)
- [Is a Pokémon energy card with no numbers normal?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/)
- [Are there games with board presentation similar to Talisman and Relic?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13884/)
- [Can I cast Enchant Creature cards on Enchantment Creatures (Bestow) that are on another creature?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14892/) (Magic cards could maybe removed altogether?)
- [What's the difference between a Euchre, a March and a Set?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/)  (via screenshots - the images were magical links directly into Google Books!)
- [Can a Dimir Keyrune receive a Cipher, and does the encoded spell stay?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12662/)
- [Exploring locations in Pathfinder](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33337/)
- [Can I tap fewer than 7 creatures with Lullmage Mentor?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/)
- [What is the memory-style game that has pawn-like tokens covering pictures?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/)
- [Is the 4-player variant unbalanced? Is there a fix?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11173/)
- [Did Wizards ever write a followup for the 2003 card face redesign?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28709/) (We want to keep the Magic cards in this one, since it's about the visual design)
- [MTG: What set is Seelenruhe (Tranquility in German) from?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23709/)  (image gone)
- [Mishra's Factory - Rarity and Peasant/Pauper Legality](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/20880/)
- [Does a God's own mana cost count towards its own devotion?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27104/)
- [Where are the building entrances in Zombies?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/)
- [Soviet space exploration board game (now with pictures)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/)
- [Looking for a really dizzying boardgame](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/22552/)

Comment: Is it worth dividing the "Completed" into ones where we've reuploaded the image and ones where we removed the image entirely?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much, unless you think you want someone else to look at it. The goal here is just to fix things.

Comment: I guess that's all of them? We're done with this?

Comment: Looks like it! Thanks for getting us started and doing so many of them.

Comment: And thank you for all of your help with creating the list and completing so many others!